# Understanding of SQL SErver Stored Procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

```
Create  PROCEDURE alertCount 
(
@field1 VARCHAR(200),
@field2 INT,
@field3 INT,
@field4 INT,
@field5 INT,
@field6 INT,

@noOfCount INT  OUT        
)
AS
BEGIN
SELECT @noOfCount = COUNT(*) from tableA
END
```

I'm very new to stored procedure and based on some tutorial, the code above helps me to create a procedure (I hope it works fine).

```
Declare @noOfCount as INT
Exec alertCount asd, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, @noOfCount
select @noOfCount
```

Now the above code suppose to return me 9 as there are 9 rows of records in my tableA but its returning me `null` instead. May I know what's wrong with it?

**P/S:** Please don't bother about the logic. I'm just trying to understand a very simple stored procedure. Thank You.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to pass parameter with `out` (or `output` keyword)

```
Declare @noOfCount as INT
Exec usp_AlertCount asd, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, @noOfCount out
select @noOfCount
```

From my expirience, it's also better to pass parameters by names (easier to maintain):

```
declare @noOfCount int

exec usp_AlertCount
    @field1 = 'asd',
    @field2 = 1,
    @field3 = 1,
    @field4 = 1,
    @field5 = 1,
    @field6 = 1, 
    @noOfCount = @noOfCount output

select @noOfCount
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ec125/4)</kbd>**